# Medications for asthma

Tags: side-effects, medications, asthma

What are the medications that are available for treating asthma? Do they have any side effects or long term effects on the patient's body?

Comment: This depends on your condition and particular situation, only a doctor can determine that.

Comment: @Shlublu edited to remove that subjective aspect of the question

Comment: @woliveirajr Ok! It looks better that way.

Comment: I've voted to keep this open, based on the recent edits. I think this question is reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are long-term medications, those that will get asthma under control:

- long-acting beta-agonists: bronchodilators, they open the airways
- leukotriene modifiers: they block the components that cause inflammation
- mast cell stabilizers: they prevent / reduce the release of chemicals (from your body) that cause inflammation
- theophylline: is a bronchodilator, used to prevent nighttime attacks
- immunomodulator: when you have asthma that is allergy-related and hasn't respond to inhaled medications

Each kind has one or more available drugs, and each one can have different side effects, specially on the long term.

(Sources: http://www.webmd.com/asthma/guide/asthma-medications#1 , http://www.drugs.com/condition/asthma.html , http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/asthma/in-depth/asthma-medications/art-20045557)

Comment: Adding references would be really useful to back up this answer: (http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers).

Comment: @Shlublu : you're right, I'll do it right now

Comment: Perhaps you mean beta agonists? It seems to me that beta antagonists would make the asthma worse.

Comment: @anongoodnurse : you're right! :) Removed the wrong "ant" from my answer